# Sublime Text 2—Quickly find something on a page

Tags: sublimetext

I've been trying out Sublime for the past few days. Long-time TextMate user.

The one thing I struggle with most is finding stuff in a document. I can use <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> to find a selector, but what if I'm looking for something else, a comment maybe, or something else?

If I use <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>, Sublime will put a box around all of the instances of my search term, which isn't what I want either. Worst, it keeps a box around all of the instances:

http://cl.ly/1T3x0i2L0j2u1a0E0M12.jpg

I need to "disengage" the find before I can move on.

Is there a TextMate "QuickFind" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>) equivalent in Sublime Text?

I find searching/navigating through a document in Sublime to be really, really frustrating.

Comment: Ack. I'm an idiot. There's a "Highlight matches" button right next to the search bar that I can turn off.

Comment: I'm an idiot too.  Found this on a google search and just realized mine was turned off as well.  haha.  Vote up for bearing my embarrassment for me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After looking for a very long time, I've found it. The Sublime equivalent to Textmate's quick search/find is `Find > Incremental Find`, or `cmd+i`.

*Now*, I'm officially a Sublime convert.

Comment: What's the point of this? hitting `esc` when you find a match using `ctrl+f` does the same thing.

Comment: @StephenSarcsamKamenar there's no point. It's the only difference and it's all about personal preference.

Comment: So just to clarify, the "boxes" are optional and 100% visual then the difference between Incremental Find and regular Find is in one you use the Enter key when done and the other you use Esc?

Comment: I would like to know the difference too. What behaviour were you looking for?

Answer (score 2):

> Worst, it keeps a box around all of the instances (see screenshot: http://cl.ly/1T3x0i2L0j2u1a0E0M12). I need to "disengage" the find before I can move on.

To disengage find in sublime text 2 just press Esc key.

Comment: I also recommend rebinding `Caps Lock` to `Esc`

Answer (score 0):

On top of using Find as per usual, if a find is for a small amount of characters that would appear 50 times on a page, use the [EasyMotion plugin](https://github.com/tednaleid/sublime-EasyMotion) which does that old Vim deal:

You hit the EasyMotion key, hit the character you want to match, then Sublime replaces all visible instances of that character with a letter, number, etc - you then hit that *replacement* character on your keyboard and the cursor moves to that particular instance of the character you wanted. It's a bit confusing to explain but basically, it lets you teleport to absolutely arbitrary points on any page in 3 key presses.